# Boost files in /usr/lib/ still being found by cmake while non-existent

Tags: apt, 22.04, libraries, cmake, boost

I am trying to install Boost 1.65 from source on Ubuntu 22.04. This is working fine, the libraries are installed into /usr/local/lib as expected. However, when I run CMake on my project using find_boost, CMake gives an error about boost libraries that apparently exist in /usr/lib.

```
CMake Warning at src/CMakeLists.txt:424 (add_library):
  Cannot generate a safe linker search path for target clcsim_models because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    link library [libboost_regex.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libboost_program_options.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libboost_filesystem.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libboost_thread.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
```

This is weird, because I can go into /usr/lib and see that there are NO boost libraries. Even when using locate boost | fgrep .so, it only shows my libraries in usr/local/lib (as it should). I have also tried sudo updatedb. I have tried re-installing boost using apt and then un-installing using apt as well. Not sure why CMake is thinking that those libraries still exist in /usr/lib

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* last year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

Comment: I wonder if the old locations are cached in the project's `CMakeCache.txt` file?

Comment: @steeldriver I've been clearing out the entire cmake directory each time, and in my current build folder the CMakeCache.txt file has the proper paths in it. Thanks for your idea though! I didn't check that

Comment: @guiverc it was actually on 22.04. Updated post to reflect that. In any case, by reading the post, you'd see that the nature of it wouldn't really change whether it's 22.04 or 18.04